# Compare and divide in report builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a condition I want to divide two values in report builder with same date but different sample name in the same table...
For example, in this image, I want to divide the CM2(2.85) and Raw Meal(0.58) value. their result should be 4.9. 
[image]
And if these two parameters (CM2 and Raw Meal) are not on the same date then the value should be empty or nothing. Please help I am new to report builder expression.

I've tried this expression but it does not give me what I need

```
IIf(InStr(Fields!Sample_Code.Value,"CM2") > 0, Fields!So3.Value, nothing) / IIf(InStr(Fields!Sample_Code.Value,"Raw Meal") > 0, Fields!So3.Value, nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

The record will either be CM2 or Raw Meal, but it will never contain both at the same time.  If `Fields!Sample_Code.Value = "CM2"` is true, the second half of the expression will be false, or vice-versa.  `Fields!Sample_Code.Value` can't be two different values at the same time, it can only contain the data from a single record.

Your expression will result in either:

```
nothing/Fields!So3.Value
```

or

```
Fields!So3.Value/nothing.
```

As a simplified example:

`IF( x=1 , 1 , null) / IF( x=2 , 1 , null)`

X cannot be two different values at the same time so the expression will never return a non-null result.

You'll need to join CM2 and RAW MEAL records together to evaluate them at the same time.  That would probably require a significant change to what you've posted so far.